# How to find out if url domain match email domain

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to find out if url domain match with email domain on my sign up form. I already managed to do it by comparing domains from url and email domain like this

```
if (getDomainFromUrl(url) === getDomainFromEmail(email)) {
      console.log("Match")
  } else {
      console.log("Doesn't match")
  }
```

where `getDomainFromUrl` does

```
export const getDomainFromUrl = (url) => {
    let hostname = "";

    if (url.indexOf("//") > -1) {
        hostname = url.split('/')[2];
    }
    else {
        hostname = url.split('/')[0];
    }

    hostname = hostname.split(':')[0];
    hostname = hostname.split('?')[0];
    if(hostname.split('www.')[1]) {
        hostname = hostname.split('www.')[1]
    }

    return hostname
}
```

which turns any url like https://www.example.co.uk/page1 into example.com

and `getDomainFromEmail` does

```
export const getDomainFromEmail = (email) => {
    return email.substring(email.lastIndexOf("@") + 1)
}
```

which obviously turn an email like myemail@example.com into example.com

The problem is that the url domain might contain another subdomain for example example.sub.com where the above `if` code will return false. Also email might contain a subdomain. I don't know what is the most reliable way to compare these domains

Comment: http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/docs.html You can try a URI library. This has a convenience method 'domain' that will extract the domain for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `URL` objects to get the domain from both the url and email and use regex to remove the subdomains. Something like this:

```js
const testData = [{
  url: 'http://bar.com',
  email: 'someone@bar.com'
}, {
  url: 'http://foo.bar.com',
  email: 'someone@bar.com'
}, {
  url: 'http://bar.com',
  email: 'someone@foo.bar.com'
}];

const getEmailDomain = (val) => {
  return getDomain(`http://${val}`);
}

const getDomain = (val) => {
  const host = new URL(val).host;
  return host.match(/[^.]+\.[^.]+$/)[0];
};

console.log(testData.map(o => {
  const urlDomain = getDomain(o.url);
  const emailDomain = getEmailDomain(o.email);
  const match = urlDomain === emailDomain;
  return `url domain: ${urlDomain}, email domain: ${emailDomain} | match ${match}`;
}));
```

There are a couple of things to keep in mind, I'm creating an URL from the email addresses (adding `http://` to them) which may fail in some cases (the email contains characters that are not valid for URLs) and I'm using regex to extract the domain name which may fail as well.

Comment: Thanks Titus... I'll try to implement this in my code and if it will work I'll mark your this as answered

Comment: Careful with “removing subdomains” though … `foo@baz.example.com` might more or less rightfully be considered to “belong to” `example.com`. Applying the same logic to `foo@baz.co.uk` however could be rather dangerous.

Comment: @04FS Yes, I've forgot about two levels country codes.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there's no need to manually parse URLs - we have the [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) these days.

So:

```
let url = new URL(location);
let.host; //e.g. stackoverflow.com
```

This works for sub-domains too, since they're obviously part of the host.

You can't use e-mail addresses with `URL()` so we'll do that manually, by removing everything up to and including the @ sign.

```
let addr = 'foo@bar.bar2com';
let host = addr.replace(/^[^@]+@/, ''); //bar.bar2.com
```

Comment: I think the OP expects `someone@bar.com` to match with `http://foo.bar.com` (ignore the subdomain).